Yii2: how to keep track what page the user came from?
Example: Imagine I have Page A, Page B, and Page C.
From both Page A and Page B I can access page C, and in Page C I have a "Return" button where I can go back to the page I was before.
Now imagine I have n pages where I can go to C from, how would I deal with that?
Currently I'm using $_SESSION to store these values and assigning it's values to the button's URL property, but I think that might not be the best practice since we'd fill the $_SESSION variable with a lot of useless stuff

If going back is the only reason for keeping track of visited pages then what about using  javascript's history.back()?

If I understand correctly what you need is a breadcrumb. You are correct, as yes you need to track on the $_SESSION of URLs array were the user has been. But you also needs to check  if the user is back on a previous visited page and rollback the array to that position.

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']?

I guess you need a breadcrumbtrail.
First you have to create the breadcrumb widget in your layoutfile, eg. main.php.
    <?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
            'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
        ]) ?>

You can add some fixed links, like "HOME" of "BACK" by adding the following code before the widget.
.
        // back-button in breadcrumbs
    if (!empty($this->params['breadcrumbs'])) {
        array_unshift(
            $this->params['breadcrumbs'],
            [
                'label' => 'BACK',
                'url' => Yii::$app->request->referrer,
                'title' => Yii::t('app', 'back'),
            ]
        );
    }

read more info about breadcrumbs
Second, you can add breadcrumbs to you trail in the view-file by adding values to $this->parameters['breadcrumbs'].
eg.
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'name of breadcrumb'), 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

The first example has a link to another page, the second one show just the title of the page without a link.
more info
